# How to reference a dynamic range

Tags: vb.net, excel

In the procedure below my combobox populate with the values of a6 through a12. However, I just realized that the range will be dynamic. There may be 3 cells or 1000 depending on the data. How can I adjust the code below to reflect a dynamic range?

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class dsbPositionBoard

   Private Sub dsbPositionBoard_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

      'This event runs when the dsbPositionBoard starts up. The procedure
      'checks for the values in column A of the allPositionsAnualized sheet
      'and populates the combobox with those values.

      'Variables for procedure
      Dim WB As Excel._Workbook
      Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
      Dim rng As Excel.Range
      Dim rngArr As String


      WB = CType(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)
      WS = DirectCast(WB.Sheets("allPositionsAnnualized"), Excel.Worksheet)
      rng = DirectCast(WS.Range("A6", "A12"), Excel.Range)
      rngArr = String.Empty

      'Build a string array delimited by commas
      For i As Integer = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
         Dim oCell As Excel.Range = DirectCast(rng.Rows(i), Excel.Range)
         rngArr &= DirectCast(oCell.Value.ToString, String) & ","
      Next

      rngArr = rngArr.Remove(rngArr.Length - 1, 1)
      cmbSelectPosition.Items.AddRange(rngArr.Split(","c))
      rng = Nothing
      WS = Nothing

   End Sub
```

Comment: follow the instructions on [Siddharth's blog](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/10/02/find-last-row-in-an-excel-sheetvbavb-net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no blank cells from A6 downwards then:

```
rng = DirectCast(WS.Range("A6", WS.Range("A6").End(xlDown)), Excel.Range)
```

You'll probably need to qualify the `xlDown` when running this from VB.NET, using `Excel.xlDirection.xlDown`.

But you should also study the link that mehow provided.